# Spectrum of translation operator in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

From exam preperation. I consider the operator $T f(x) := f(x − 1), x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. First on the space of all function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. There I found that any number other than $0$ is an eigenvalue. Now it is claimed in the exercise that $T$ has no eigenvalues when $T : L^2
(\mathbb{R}) → L^
2
(\mathbb{R})$.

Why is that? How does it change the argument, that the function is in $L^
2(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because constant functions, except $0$, are not elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as they have an infinite integral.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, thank you!

Comment: I do not see, why this should answer the question. Constant functions are candidates for eigenvectors only for eigenvalue 1. What about other eigenvalues?

Comment: The question was "How does it change the argument" and I answered that question. If you want a proof that there are no eigenvalues of the given form, that is indeed another story. Basically, assuming $f\neq0$ we find a measurable set $S$ of positive measure where the integral of $f$ is non-zero. We then find that for some $n$ the set $S\cap[n,n+1]$ has the same property. Then copying this set all over the number line we find that $f$ has an infinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be an eigenfunction to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. 
Since $f\in L^2$, we have
$$
\|f\|_{L^2}^2 = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\int_{(k,k+1)} f^2 dx=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z:-n\le k<n}\int_{(k,k+1)} f^2 dx.
$$
Due to the eigenvalue property,
$$
\int_{(n,n+1)} f^2 dx = \lambda^n \int_{(0,1)} f^2dx
$$
for all $n$,
which implies
$$
\|f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{(0,1)} f^2dx \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z:-n\le k<n}\lambda^k.
$$
The left-hand side is a finite number, so the right-hand side has to be finite, which implies $\int_{(0,1)} f^2dx =0$ or $\lambda=0$. Both imply $f=0$, which is a contradiction $f$ being an eigenfunction.

Comment: I have a similar problem I'm looking at with slight modifications. How would this change if we were using the space $L_{p}(\mathbb{R}_{+})$ and using $Tf=f(x+1)$ instead of $Tf=f(x-1)$? I'm thinking we might actually get $\lambda$ that work. I just dont see how the relation "$\int_{(n,n+1)} f^2 dx = \lambda^n \int_{(0,1)} f^2dx$" would change.

Comment: @Kevin  Please ask this as a separate question! The problem changes completely because of that $-1$. For instance, your $T$ has nontrivial null space.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll go ahead and do that.

Comment: Hi, wouldn't the same argument work for $L^p$ instead of $L^2$?

Comment: @user8469759 yes

Comment: And isn't the conclusion that $T -\lambda e$ can be inverted for every $\lambda \neq 0$? If $|\lambda| > 1$ I can invert $T - \lambda e$ by using the Neumann series, but what if $|\lambda | \leq 1$? Can the inverse be computed as well somewhat?