# Point spectrum of translation operator in $L_{P}[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039720/spectrum-of-translation-operator-in-l2/3039871?noredirect=1#comment6904929_3039871) post. Consider the space $L_{p}[0,\infty)$ and the operator $(Tf)(t)=f(t+a)$ for $a>0$. How could one go about finding the point spectrum of such an operator? I understand that this means finding the eigenvalues or $\lambda$ such that

$$\tag{1}(Tf)(t)=\lambda f(t)$$
is satisfied.

Taking inspiration from daw's answer we can write,

$\tag{2} \|f\|^p = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_{(ka,(k+1)a)} f^p dt=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\int_{(ka,(k+1)a)} f^p dt.$

Here is where I'm stuck, I'm dealing with a left shift operator but I don't know how to implement that as well as the assumption that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $f$. I don't know specifically how I can use the left shift to rewrite

$$ \int_{(ka,(k+1)a)} f^p dt$$
in terms of $\lambda$. Any help would be appreciated.

Attempted solution:

By assumption $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ so, $$\tag{3} \int_{(ak,(k+1)a)} f^p dt = \lambda^n \int_{(0,1)} f^p dt$$

So (2) and (3) yield,
\begin{align*}
\|f\|^p &= \int_{(0,1)} f^pdt \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda^k.
\end{align*}

Since $f\in L_{p}(\mathbb{R}_{+})$ and the LHS is finite we must have that $|\lambda|<1$ for (1) to hold.

Comment: Oh here $a>0$ so $f(t+a)$ is a left shift.

Comment: You can use the same reasoning as in my answer. Just replace the intervals $(k,k+1)$ by $(ka,(k+1)a)$. Then you get a necessary conditionf for $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Any $\lambda<1$ should be in the point-spectrum. Let $f$ be $1$ on $(0,a)$, then $\lambda$ on $(a,2a)$, then $\lambda^2$ on $(2a,3a)$ and so on. The measure of $f^p$ is $a\sum_{n=0}\lambda^{pn}$, which is finite for $\lambda<1$. The $\lambda ≥1$ cannot be in the point spectrum as the any such function cannot have finite measure.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks, I knew that this was the interpretation but I just wanted to write some stuff down using a more direct approach. Looks like with your method we can say that the eigenfunction will just be a simple function defined to be $\lambda^k$ on $(ka,(k+1)a)$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $a>0$, the point spectrum is $\{\lambda\in\Bbb C:|\lambda|<1\}$ for  $1\le p<\infty$ and $\{|\lambda|\le1\}$ for $p=\infty$.

Suppose first that $p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p$. Then it's clear that $||T^nf||_p\to0$; if $Tf=\lambda f$ this implies $\lambda^n\to0$ so $|\lambda|<1$.

Conversely, suppose $|\lambda|<1$. There exists $\alpha$ with $\Re\alpha>0$ and $$\lambda=e^{-\alpha a}.$$Let $$f(t)=e^{-\alpha t};$$then $f\in L^p$ since $p<\infty$ and $Tf=e^{-\alpha a}f=\lambda f$.

We leave the modifications for $p=\infty$ to you...